#  iwl3945 vs. iwlwifi, what are the differences?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, intel-wireless

Is there a different Wifi driver to try or do I have the 'best' one already?
I have a stock installation of Ubuntu Natty (11.04) on a HP Laptop with this 
Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)

lsmod | grep iwl shows:

```
iwl3945               126017  0 
iwlcore               148964  1 iwl3945
mac80211              257001  2 iwl3945,iwlcore
cfg80211              156212  3 iwl3945,iwlcore,mac80211
```

I've read about a driver from Intel called iwlwifi.  Is this what I have?  Is there a different driver to try?  My wifi works fine, but I'm trying to see if there is anyway to lower it's power consumption.  powertop shows iwl3945 always at #2 with ~30%.

Comment: FYI, I was able to lower my power consumption with:
    `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 5dBm`
Since this driver does not allow setting the power timeout.  YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iwl3945` module is a driver from the `iwlwifi` project.  The other drivers from the project are `iwl4965` and `iwlagn`, which target different generations of the Intel Wifi hardware.

There was an older driver available for your card by the name `ipw3945`, but Ubuntu hasn't shipped with a kernel that featured the driver for some time (it was superseded by the newer `iwlwifi` drivers).